# Flash banner not clickable in chrome

Tags: wordpress, flash, google-chrome, clickable

I have embedded a flash banner on my wordpress site, by editing the header.php file. The banner itself has been hardcoded with the link, but once its on my website it is not clickable in Chrome (FF and IE work fine).

I then added another banner using the same code (except for the file name), which works on all browsers (the second banner was added using a widget).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Y.

The banner can be found above the header, here: http://wordsandmusic.me

This is the code I am using:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="728" HEIGHT="90" id="http://wordsandmusic.me/wp-content/uploads/Flash Banners/banner_02.swf" ALIGN="Middle">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="http://wordsandmusic.me/wp-content/uploads/Flash Banners/banner_02.swf"> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> <PARAM NAME=AllowScriptAccess VALUE="always"> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399> <EMBED src="http://wordsandmusic.me/wp-content/uploads/Flash Banners/banner_02.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="728" HEIGHT="90" NAME="http://wordsandmusic.me/wp-content/uploads/Flash Banners/banner_02.swf" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" AllowScriptAccess="always"></EMBED> </OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to delete this:

```
<div class="background-cover"></div>
```

Or at least modify the rules for that class. What are you using that div for?

Comment: Thats part of the theme code. How does it affect this?

Comment: I'm not sure why is there it could be a widget container or something like that, but by being above the banner you can't click it.

Comment: And it makes sense that this will only occur in chrome?

Comment: Ok, I have removed the div you mentioned and everything seems to be working well now. Any chance there will be any consequences?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know, I didn't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css code to the `<div>` which contains the flash object:

```
<div style="text-align:center;position:relative;z-index:1;">
   <object>Flash object will come here</object>
</div>
```

I have added inline css in the above code.